# Foreman gem is not loading my services from Procfile, they always fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreman

Using Foreman GEM on my local development OSX I have problems making it launch all my services correctly. I have had issues with it so I manually copy and paste the lines from the Procfile on every reboot. Very frustrating

This is my
**Procfile.rb:**

```
redis: redis-server
resque: bundle exec rake resque:start  &&> log/resque_worker_queue.log
privpub: bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production & &> log/private_pub.log
sunspot: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

I always have to manually start all of them by copy paste the commands in terminal foreman start does not work, what am i missing?

**This is foreman output:**

```
    16:13:24 redis.1    | started with pid 11281
16:13:24 resque.1   | started with pid 11282
16:13:24 privpub.1  | started with pid 11283
16:13:24 sunspot.1  | started with pid 11284
16:13:24 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:24 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
16:13:24 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:24 * Server started, Redis version 2.4.13
16:13:24 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:24 * DB loaded from disk: 0 seconds
16:13:24 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:24 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
16:13:25 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:25 - DB 0: 21 keys (0 volatile) in 48 slots HT.
16:13:25 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:25 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 955424 bytes in use
16:13:26 privpub.1  | /Users/jordan.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:43:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/jordan/rails/books/log/private_pub.log (LoadError)
16:13:26 privpub.1  |   from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:43:in `parse_file'
16:13:26 privpub.1  |   from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
16:13:26 privpub.1  |   from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
16:13:26 privpub.1  |   from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
16:13:26 privpub.1  |   from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
16:13:26 privpub.1  |   from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
16:13:26 privpub.1  |   from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
16:13:26 privpub.1  |   from /Users/jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
16:13:26 privpub.1  | process terminated
16:13:26 system     | sending SIGTERM to all processes
16:13:26 system     | sending SIGTERM to pid 11281
16:13:26 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:26 # Received SIGTERM, scheduling shutdown...
16:13:26 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:26 # User requested shutdown...
16:13:26 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:26 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
16:13:26 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:26 * DB saved on disk
16:13:26 redis.1    | [11281] 04 Jun 16:13:26 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
16:13:26 system     | sending SIGTERM to pid 11282
16:13:26 resque.1   | rake aborted!
16:13:26 resque.1   | SIGTERM
16:13:26 resque.1   | 
16:13:26 resque.1   | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
16:13:26 system     | sending SIGTERM to pid 11284
16:13:26 sunspot.1  | rake aborted!
16:13:26 sunspot.1  | SIGTERM
16:13:26 sunspot.1  | 
16:13:26 sunspot.1  | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
16:13:26 sunspot.1  | process terminated
16:13:26 resque.1   | process terminated
16:13:26 redis.1    | process terminated
```

Comment: is there any output from foreman start?

Comment: Are you using an alternative Procfile, like Procfile.dev, maybe? Then you should run foreman like so: `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`.

Comment: no I'm just using foreman start with a regular Procfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your output redirects by changing the 2nd and 3rd lines to:

```
resque: bundle exec rake resque:start
privpub: bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
```

Foreman might have issues w/ redirects in commands: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/search?q=redirect